# How to Run a Common JSP Page on the Server

Tags: java, jquery, jsp

I don't know if I wrote the correct question but this is what I want to do:

In the main page `index.jsp` I have a `DIV`.

```
<div id="test">
</div>
```

Using `JQUERY` I'm gonna load another `JSP` page inside this `DIV`.

```
$("#test").load("chat.jsp");
```

In chat.jsp I'm gonna use a TIMER or THREAD to print a message every 5 seconds.

```
<% out.println("Welcome"); %>
```

or

```
<%="Welcome"%>
```

Let's say there's two Clients who are going to access load the `chat.jsp` page, Client A and Client B, and this page is running on the server, it printed "Welcome" at `12:00:00` and it will print another "Welcome" at `12:00:05`.

Let's say Client A loaded the page at `12:00:01`, and Client B loaded the page at `12:00:04`.

I want both Clients to receive a "Welcome" at `12:00:05`, not at `12:00:06` (for A) and `12:00:09` (for B).

What is the best approach to do this?

Comment: did you even check the answer to you questions.

Answer (score 0):

Generate the time once and send it to both if you want to make sure that they  receive the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Well , If you are looking for an approach then would suggest you to use the `mod %` operator to get the remainder and then using some `if-else` `conditional construct` to go for the

nearest multiple of `5` by applying some basic logic e.g. `floor-ceiling values` to get the value. Rest is unto you and your approach.